# Return numerous SQL results to C# array

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have seen a few questions asked about this kind of thing already, but whenever I try anything it just doesn't work with this exact instance. I have a remote SQL SERVER database set up, and it has over 2000 rows.

This is my C#:

```
command.Connection = connectionString;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "SELECT IconUrl FROM Items WHERE DefIndex IN " + iconSqlString;
connection.Open();
string iconString = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
connection.Close();
```

I do have the SqlConnection set up and all that, I just don't think it is necessary to be included.

iconSqlString is in the format of `(32, 126, 68)`. The string has over 150 items and is different each time. I need to return the IconUrl for all items in the string. The current query for some reason only returns on IconUrl, for the item with the value of 35 in the 51st position (out of 196). I know that the iconString is in the format of a string, but it is only for testing purposes, I was expecting it to have returned all the results, separated by commas or something else. I wish to return all the values possible to an array, to be called later with something like sqlItem[5]. How would I do this?

Comment: A scalar is a single result. You want [ExecuteReader()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. There's an example of how to use it at the bottom of that linked-to page.

Comment: Thanks so much, if you want to provide this as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as answer : )

Comment: [Beware of little bobby tables.](https://xkcd.com/327/) Use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExecuteScalar is for single result, you will need to use [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Also as a side note, you should never use variables to perform a query because of an attack called SQLI or [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Here is a link with some examples on [how to execute parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: The data used in the string is retrieved from an API using purely code behind, would SQL injection still be an issue in this case?

Comment: There's always a way to compromise a system. Not knowing your current system architecture I would still recommend using parameterized queries. Better safe than sorry.